# Rails simple file download

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi help me in simple question:

how to released simple download:

i my public/data i have some.txt or some.pdf file ( with some text )

and i want to user click in some button and start download this file.

i do something like that

```
<%= link_to "Terms" ,:action => :download, :file_name => 'some.txt' %>

def download
    send_file "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/data/#{params[:file_name]}", :type=>"application/zip"
end
```

But what to do next?

PS if you have some tutorial or example on this subject (like downloading file), I would be very grateful

[image]

Comment: What happens when you click the link? Are you getting any error?

Comment: i got No route matches {:action=>"download", :file_name=>"some.txt", :controller=>"posts"} /// i am newbie in rails and routes put in routes.rb

Comment: Can you post the contents of your routes.rb file?

Comment: i saw that i don't "announce" action download - how i can fix that ? ( i update post )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely missing a route in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts do
  get :download, :on => :collection

  resource :comments
end
```

and then you can have a link like:

```
<%= link_to "Terms" ,:action => :download, :file_name => 'some.txt' %>
```

that will probably generate something like:

```
<a href="/posts/download?file_name=some.txt">Terms</a>
```

I think it's still not the best solution, but solves your problem.

I recommend a quick look at this part of the Rails Guides to clarify this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

A complete read of this guides is always good and highly recommended too.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean "what next"? Apart from the fact that the application/zip mime type doesn't match your file's (which is .txt, so presumable text/plain) what you wrote is essentially correct.

Two things to keep in mind, since your file is in the public directory you don't strictly need to use `send_file` through the controller, you could just write this instead:

```
<%= link_to "Terms", '/data/some.txt' %>
```

And second if you're going to use `send_file` to server larger files you might want to look in to xsendfile instead which improves performance. This has to be supported by your webserver though (using mod_sendfile for apache for example.)

But all that said your code should work as is.

Comment: i had routing error, I just started learning rails, and many do not understand. And in you example ( '/data/some.txt.') ->  i get "No route matches [GET] "/data/some.txt" "

Comment: Strange, whatever is in your public directory should be available directly without Rails intervening. Reading the error you wrote in your comment above also seems strange. The download action is defined in the PostsController right? It sounds like something weird is going on with your routes. Could you add your routes.rb file (at least the posts route) to your question so we can check it?

Comment: o i fix this problem - and all working, but when i cick link, is the opening page with some.txt content - but how can i realize that: click on link - and opening 'prompt' window which asks 'save the file or not and choose directory where you want save file ' - standart ask before saving

Comment: If you're still using send_file, you can set the `content_disposition` which indicates how you want the client to handle the file. For example: `send_file "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/data/#{params[:file_name]}", :content_disposition => 'attachment', :type => "application/zip"`